# Como é que posso mostar imagens(url) da BD (MySQL) no Android Studio

Tags: mysql, android

Como é que posso mostar imagens (url) da Base de Dados (MySQL) no Android Studio?

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.APP;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String urladdress="http://3m22p.dx.am/app_conexao.php";
    String[] nome;
    String[] comentarios;
    String[] imagem;
    ListView ListView;
    BufferedInputStream is;
    String line = null;
    String result = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lview);

        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy((new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitNetwork().build()));
        collectData();
        CustomListView customListView = new CustomListView(this,nome,comentarios,imagem);
        ListView.setAdapter(customListView);
    }
    private void collectData()
    {
        //conexão
        try{
            URL url = new URL(urladdress);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            is = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Conteudo

        try{
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = br.readLine())!=null){
                sb.append(line+"\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        //JSON

        try{
            JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject jo = null;
            nome = new String[ja.length()];
            comentarios = new String[ja.length()];
            imagem = new String[ja.length()];

            for (int i=0;i<=ja.length();i++){
                jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                nome[i] = jo.getString("nome");
                comentarios[i] = jo.getString("comentarios");
                imagem[i] = jo.getString("imagens");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

CustomListView.java

```
package com.example.APP;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.InputStream;


public class CustomListView extends ArrayAdapter <String>{

    private  String[] nomes_col;
    private  String[] comentarios;
    private  String[] imagem;
    private Activity context;
    Bitmap bitmap;

    public CustomListView(Activity context,String[] nomes_col,String[] comentarios,String[] imagem) {
        super(context, R.layout.layout,nomes_col);
        this.context=context;
        this.nomes_col=nomes_col;
        this.comentarios=comentarios;
        this.imagem=imagem;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override

    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent){

        View r = convertView;
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if (r==null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            r = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout,null,true);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder(r);
            r.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder)r.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.tvw1.setText(nomes_col[position]);
        viewHolder.tvw2.setText(comentarios[position]);
        new GetImageFromURL(viewHolder.ivw).execute(imagem[position]);

        return r;
    }
    class ViewHolder{
        TextView tvw1;
        TextView tvw2;
        ImageView ivw;

        ViewHolder(View v){
            tvw1 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvprofilename);
            tvw2 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvcomentarios);
            ivw = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
        }
    }
    public class GetImageFromURL extends AsyncTask<String,Void, Bitmap>{

        ImageView imgView;
        public GetImageFromURL(ImageView imgv){
            this.imgView = imgv;
        }
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... url) {
            String urldisplay = url[0];
            bitmap = null;

            try{
                InputStream ist = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ist);
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap){

            super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
            imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

BD em MySQL
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código php do ficheiro: app_conexao.php
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: sua pergunta é muito ampla, não consegue reduzir pra um problema mais específico? pode compartilhar o código do que já fez?

Comment: Ja pus ai em cima bro

Comment: Use a biblioteca Glide ou picasso

Comment: Como é que insiro no meu código Murilo ?

Comment: A partir do momento onde, no seu código tem  String urladdress="http://3m22p.dx.am/app_conexao.php"; isso parece significar que a base de dados esta num servidor Web, ao seja, não esta no Android.
Neste caso, não é um problema de Android mas um problema de PHP. Quem faz o codigo de app_conexao.php? Vc?

Comment: vou por o codigo do ficheiro php acima, Peter

Comment: Ah OK! Na BDD vc tem URL da imagen e vc quer mostra a imagem no Android? Isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ver no android uma imagem quando vc tem URL:

```
 URL url_img = new URL("http://meu_servido.com/image.jpg");
 Bitmap data_bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url_img.openConnection().getInputStream());
 imageView.setImageBitmap(data_bmp);
```

E suficiente mudar o nome do URL conforme na valor que tem na base de dados. Por exemple se na BDD a imagem tem so o nome (eg "casa") basta "colar" tudo junto tipo
url_img = "http://meu_servidor.com/"+nome_na_BDD+".jpg";
No caso d imagem "casa", vai dar http://meu_servidor.com/casa.jpg, no caso de "bicicleta" vai dar http://meu_servidor.com/bicicleta.jpg etc...

Comment: Mas eu não quero uma imagem em especifico, quero que cada nome tenha a sua propia imagem, que foi colocada (através de um link) na BD

Comment: Fiz modicação na resposta. Depois, depende do que vc tem na sua base. Saber se vc tem o URL completa, so um pedaço etc...

Answer (score 0):

Utilize biblioteca pra fazer isso, facilita.

Primeiro acrescente a biblioteca em build.gradle(app):

```
implementation group: 'com.github.bumptech.glide', name: 'glide', version: '4.9.0'
```

Dentro do seu adapter ao invés de usar:

```
new GetImageFromURL(viewHolder.ivw).execute(imagem[position]);
```

use:

```
    //método da biblioteca para carregar as imagens
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(imagem[position])
                .apply(new RequestOptions()
                        .override(90, 90)). //aqui você define altura e largura em px
                into(viewHolder.ivw);
```

Desse modo você pode excluir o método que criou de asynctask

Comment: ok Obrigado vou tentar isso

Comment: És o maior, oh bro FUNCIONA! Muito Obrigado.

Comment: @TurmaBciccopn Se puder marcar minha resposta como útil, ajuda outros usuários.